# Powershell LocalBackup New-PSDrive Destination Fault

Tags: powershell, logging, backup

I want to take backup from server to local bu when I look at the log file it is giving error from New-PSDrive.

Error part in LocalBackup file :

#### Mount Backup Sources

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "B" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.

At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:57 char:5
+     New-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0] -Root $BkpSrc[1] -PSProvider FileSys ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (S:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root ":" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:57 char:5
+     New-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0] -Root $BkpSrc[1] -PSProvider FileSys ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

#### Mounting Backup Destinations

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "B" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:62 char:5
+     New-PSDrive -Name $BkpDst[0] -Root $BkpDst[1] -PSProvider FileSys ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (S:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root ":" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:62 char:5
+     New-PSDrive -Name $BkpDst[0] -Root $BkpDst[1] -PSProvider FileSys ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

ERROR : No Destination Directory Specified.

```
   Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

         source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
    destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
           /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?
```

****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !

****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !

#### Unmount Backup Sources

Remove-PSDrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'S' does not exist.
At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:81 char:5
+     Remove-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0] *>>$LogPath/$Logfile
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (S:String) [Remove-PSDrive], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand

Remove-PSDrive : Cannot remove drive 'C' because it is in use.
At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:81 char:5
+     Remove-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0] *>>$LogPath/$Logfile
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-PSDrive], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand

#### Unmount Backup Sources

Remove-PSDrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'S' does not exist.
At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:86 char:5
+     Remove-PSDrive -Name $BkpDst[0] *>>$LogPath/$Logfile
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (S:String) [Remove-PSDrive], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand

Remove-PSDrive : Cannot remove drive 'C' because it is in use.
At C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug\Untitled2.ps1:86 char:5
+     Remove-PSDrive -Name $BkpDst[0] *>>$LogPath/$Logfile
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-PSDrive], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand

I am admin in the system I searched from internet and ByPass the Execution Policy and Credentials it is looking okay but still it is not working.

Code Part :

```
 # @(DstName,Path)

 $BackupDestinations =   @(

 , @('Batch','\\srvr0001\TEMP\trying3')

 , @('test2','\\srvr0002\TEMP\trying2')
                          )
 # @(SrcName,Path,DstName)
 $BackupSources = @(
 , @('abcde','C:\Temp\ProjectCopy\Backup\Archives\Batch','Batch')
 , @('defgh','C:\Temp\Project - Copy\Backup\Archives\WinCCTag','test2')
                   )
 $LogPath = "C:\Temp\trying2adm_trerulug"

 $LogVersion = 50

 If (-Not (Test-Path $LogPath)){mkdir $LogPath}
 While ($LogVersion -gt 0)
 {
 $OldLogfile = "LocalBackup.$LogVersion.log"
 $Logfile = "LocalBackup.$($LogVersion-1).log"

 Copy-Item -Path $LogPath\$Logfile -Destination $LogPath\$OldLogFile -

 ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 $LogVersion-- 

 }
 echo $null > $LogPath\$Logfile

 Function Write-Log{

 Param([string]$logstring)

 # Write-Host $LogPath\$LogFile

 Add-Content -Path $LogPath\$LogFile $logstring

 }

 $RoboArgs = 
 $("/E","/Z","/COPY:DAT","/R:3","/W:10","/XN","/XO","/XX","/NP")

 # Mount PSDrives
 ## Backup Sources
 Write-Log "### Mount Backup Sources ##########################"

 Foreach($BkpSrc in $BackupSources){

 New-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0] -Root $BkpSrc[1] -PSProvider FileSystem 

 *>>$LogPath/$Logfile
 }
 ## Backup Destinations

 Write-Log "### Mounting Backup Destinations ##################"

 Foreach($BkpDst in $BackupDestinations){

 New-PSDrive -Name $BkpDst[0] -Root $BkpDst[1] -PSProvider FileSystem 

 *>>$LogPath/$Logfile
 }

 # Copy Backups

 Write-Log "### Start copyjobs ################################"

 Foreach($BkpSrc in $BackupSources){

 # Select right source directory

 Foreach($BkpDst in $BackupDestinations){

 if ($BkpDst[0] -eq $BkpSrc[2]){

 $BkpDstPath = $BkpDst[1]
 }
 }
 robocopy $BkpSrc[1] $BkpDstPath $RoboArgs *>>$LogPath/$Logfile
 }

 # Unmount the PSDrives

 ## Backup Sources

 Write-Log "### Unmount Backup Sources ########################"

 Foreach($BkpSrc in $Backupsources){

 Remove-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0] *>>$LogPath/$Logfile

 }
 ## Backup Destinations

 Write-Log "### Unmount Backup Sources ########################"

 Foreach($BkpDst in $BackupDestinations){

 Remove-PSDrive -Name $BkpDst[0] *>>$LogPath/$Logfile

 }
```

Comment: this >>> `$BackupDestinations =   @(` <<< does not have a closing `)` - nor does the sources list.. [*grin*] ///// also, what line is reported in the error? also also, what is the EXACT COMPLETE error? ///// even more ALSO - have you added a `-WhatIf` to the line that is triggering your error so that you can see what it is trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is caused by the way you build your `$BackupDestinations` & `$BackupSources` collections. you do NOT have an array of arrays ... you have an array of strings. so `$BckSrc[0]` is the 1st letter in the current item in your `foreach` loop. [*grin*]

either switch to using a hashtable OR use the `,` array operator to force the sub-arrays to be added as *sub-arrays* instead of as lists of items.

if you want to stick with arrays, use something like this [note the leading comma before each sub-array] ...

```
$BackupSources = @(
    , @('abcde','C:\Temp\ProjectCopy\Backup\Archives\Batch','Batch')
    , @('defgh','C:\Temp\Project - Copy\Backup\Archives\WinCCTag','test2')
    )
```

---

with the following code, AND no PSDrives using the names in your list, AND the target dirs already created --- there are no error messages about creating OR removing the PSDrives in question.

```
$BackupDestinations =   @(
, @('Batch','\\srvr0001\TEMP\trying3')
, @('test2','\\srvr0002\TEMP\trying2')
                        )

$BackupSources = @(
, @('abcde','C:\Temp\ProjectCopy\Backup\Archives\Batch','Batch')
, @('defgh','C:\Temp\Project - Copy\Backup\Archives\WinCCTag','test2')
                )

Foreach ($BkpSrc in $BackupSources)
    {
    New-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0] -Root $BkpSrc[1] -PSProvider FileSystem #-WhatIf
    }

Get-PSDrive | Out-Host

'=' * 20 | Out-Host

#<#
Foreach ($BkpSrc in $Backupsources)
    {
    Remove-PSDrive -Name $BkpSrc[0]
    pause
    }
Get-PSDrive
#>
```

so ... what part of your code is generating the errors you list in you Original Post?

Comment: I believe, this should be enough: `$BackupSources =
 ('abcde','C:\Temp\ProjectCopy\Backup\Archives\Batch','Batch'),
 ('defgh','C:\Temp\Project - Copy\Backup\Archives\WinCCTag','test2')
`

Comment: Thank your so much for feedbacks it's my fault I forgot to add "," now I can send the files but in backup file still it's giving error. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
-New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "B" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
-New-PSDrive : The specified drive root ":" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.

Comment: @montonero - the comma operator is the way i usually see it done, but yours works also! [*grin*]

Comment: @ErolUluğ - you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// have you added the same leading comma for BOTH of your arrays? ///// also, have you tried adding a `-WhatIF` to your lines to see what is going wrong? [*grin*] it's painfully obvious once you see the line that PoSh is trying to run.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes I added for both array it send documents, I also tried with -WhatIF there was no problem but still in backup file I see that errors.

Comment: @ErolUluğ - please add your _current_ code & _current_ error to your Original Post so folks can see exactly what you are talking about. right now, i can only guess at what is happening ... [*grin*]

Comment: Dear @Lee_Dailey I added the current error in backup file, I hope it is understandable, thank you for understanding.

Comment: @ErolUluğ - you have NOT done the array addition correctly. [*grin*] the comma operator MUST be the 1st thing in the line. if that structure bothers you, then use the method shown by montonero in his reply to my answer.

Comment: I did say to you I added the comma(script is working) and use -WhatIf but there was no error. I can send files, I just want to figure out why in my localbackup.txt file saying cannot fin drive, cannot remove drive, No Destination Directory Specified etc. Because I want to see when some problem happen from this txt file.

Comment: @ErolUluğ - please, add to your Original Post the code you are CURRENTLY running that is creating the CURRENT errors. the errors you list are the _exact ones_ that i get when i run your _original_ code ... so i am quite confused.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I add to current code and add to localbackup.txt file faults at the top(maybe error is wrong term). I'm also quite confused like 2 days I'm searching why I can not take logs properly but couldn't find it.
For example like that error(in txt backup file) : 
ERROR : No Destination Directory Specified.
Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR
source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
 /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.
Also other errors at the top(mounting,unmount,psdrive)

Comment: @ErolUluğ - please see the code & comment i added to my answer post.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thank you for helping problem finally solved.

Comment: @ErolUluğ - you are very welcome! glad to have been a help ... [*grin*]